# Fragment creates different RatingBars when resumed

Tags: android, android-fragments, ratingbar

I have a fragment whose layout includes some RatingBars with given ratings (set dynamically). In the fragment I can click on some regions, which causes a transition to another fragment. My problem is: when I pass to the following fragment and then hit the Back button to come back to the original one, I find that the UI is exactly as before exept for the RatingBars, which have now all the same rating than the last one in the list (item2 in the code below)! Any idea of what is happening? Here is the original fragment code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    scroller = new ScrollView(getActivity());
    ln = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    ln.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    scroller.addView(ln);
    \\define items

    addItemLayout(item1, inflater, container);  
    addItemLayout(item2, inflater, container);  

    return scroller;        
}

private void addItemLayout(MyItem item, LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container){

    View uiItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, container,false);                         

    \\insert textviews...

    RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) uiItem.findViewById(R.id.rating);
    ratingBar.setRating(item.getRating());
    View content = uiItem.findViewById(R.id.content);
    final MyItem itemToPass = item;

    content.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){    
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.replace(R.id.root_frame, NextFragment.newInstance(itemToPass));
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }); 
    ln.addView(uiItem);     
}
```

and here's the ratingbar in the layout file

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        style="@style/myRatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/upperlabel"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1" />
```

So the layout of the first fragment is created perfectly at the beginning, then it is destroyed when the transaction takes place, and when it is recreated after hitting the back button it is recreated perfectly except for the ratingbars! How is it possible that the effect of the first onCreateView() is different from the effect of the same method called the second time?

EDIT: This seems to be related to the fact that I'm using custom ratingbars, because with the standard ones the problem disappears. Here's the style of my ratingbars:

```
<style name="foodRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingstars</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">16dp</item>
</style>
```

and this is the ratingstars.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+android:id/background"
      android:drawable="@drawable/emptyglass" />
<item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
      android:drawable="@drawable/emptyglass" />
<item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
      android:drawable="@drawable/fullglass" />
</layer-list>
```

where emptyglass and fullglass are two png images.